# Вызов команд ОС из Delphi

Tags: delphi, bat

В таком варианте ничего не происходит, как это правильно сделать подскажите, пожалуйста?

```
     system(' @echo ');
     system(' P: ');
     system(' cd P:\A\ ');
     system(' rar.exe a -o+ -r P:\2.rar *.* ');
```

Надо код батника переделать в код delphi. Спасибо.

Comment: Сохраните текст батника в файл, выполните батник WinExec-ом, удалите батник.

Comment: > WinExec

Вы очень любите ретро? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Создать текстовый файл shell.cmd
2. Запустить его из тела программы вызовом ShellExecute, WinExec, CreateProcess.

Пример:

```
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', '/C cd C:\shell.cmd', nil, WS_HIDE);
```

Comment: а без вызова cmd или bat никак нельзя?

Comment: Смотрите CreateProcess

Comment: ShellExecute(0,'open','E:\...\Apt.bat',nil,nil,1);

сделал так и не морочусь)